# Using make in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse 3.5, I have highlighting and outlines for Makefile. What I don't see is an option to actually run a target. So can I run `make` from Eclipse? Of course, I could just add it to External Tools, but this wouldn't let me choose a target without using a modal dialog, which kind of defeats the purpose.

If it matters, it is an Erlang project, but I've tried Resource and C/C++ perspectives as well.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ projects support building by Makefile. I can't advise on how this relates to Erlang; perhaps it's a feature you might want to ask the developers of Erlide about?